# How do I skip an Android system update and stop its notifications?

Tags: updates, nexus-5, ota-update

I get a message

```
Android 5.0.1 System Update Available
```

but no option to skip the update.

In frustration, I click "download". It's not better after the download. I still get

```
System update downloaded
```

with no option to avoid the update.

How do I signal that I am perfectly content with KitKat 4.4.4 for the time being? I use my phone for development and want to be certain my development tools are ready before upgrading. In the meantime I also want to stop  the continuous harassment via notifications. Is this possible? I am using a Nexus 5 and the phone is not rooted (I prefer it to stay that way).

Comment: As a pop-up or as something in the notification bar? What happens when you go to settings > apps > goggle services framework and turn off notifications?

Comment: @LivedWithOtters Your suggestion did indeed stop the notifications briefly, but they soon resumed appearing (even though the notifications remain turned off for g.s.f.). The notification is permanently visible in the notification bar and also permanently visible in the notification screen (the double-swipe-down screen).

Comment: @LivedWithOtters you were right in the direction, but instead it was Services not framework.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just spoke to Google directly. The Nexus 5 under settings, apps has something called Google Play services. Not store. If you uncheck the notification box in Google Play services and restart the phone the notification for the Android system updates will stop in the notification bar. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but  it seems you must be rooted to do this.

Comment: After updating to Lollipop 5.1.1, the notifications checkbox is rechecked for you. Thankfully, it's still there, and it does stop the new ongoing messages to update to 6.0.

Comment: Worked fine on my Nexus 7 2012. Not rooted.

Comment: @stevensmith absolutely NOT. That is an option available in all apps that have notifications.

Comment: You can long-press the update **notification**, then, click on the "i" icon, and you'll get to the same place to toggle `block all`. (No root needed. Tested on 6.0.1)

Comment: I have just downgraded from 6.0.1 to 5.0 because after the update I was getting random lock screen crashes and then reboots (which meant I had to use my password next time I used Android Pay, very annoying). Now on 5.0, instantly got the software update notification, did as said above, works perfect. Galaxy S5, not rooted.

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be rooted, you should be able to install [Disable Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice) and find the `SystemUpdateService` under *Google Play Services* disable *Google Services Framework*.

Comment: They moved the service under "Google Play Services". At least it's true for Android 6.

Comment: @McTrafik is right. On Android 6, go to Disable Services → Google Play Services → disable `SystemUpdateService` (and possibly `SystemUpdateGcmTaskService` too).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out :D :D

If you get the notification and have not yet downloaded the update. Simply Press the notification in the notification bar and Hold for 10 Seconds. It will give you two options. Click on the Settings button. From Settings select "Turn off notifications update" :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear data for downloading application (DMClient)

1. open system nofitication bar
2. hold touch on system downloading bar until it pop up app info
3. touch App info it will go to DMClient app info
4. touch clear data button under Storage
5. then touch OK for Delete app data question

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 there's an option to turn off automatic updates in the Developer Options [1](https://kaanuzdogan.com/avoid-updating-your-xiaomi-mi-a-3-to-android-11-for-now) [2](https://lifehacker.com/how-do-i-block-android-from-installing-system-updates-1836701683). It seems to be available since Nougat [3](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/15/android-n-feature-spotlight-automatic-system-updates-can-be-disabled-in-developer-options/) [4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/automatic-system-updates-in-developer-options.3697351/)

Comment: Is this for everybody or is it restricted to just a number of device manufacturers? Source of this "fact"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It's available in Mi A3 and Android One devices. Since all Android devices have Developer Options it should be available to most up to date devices. I'll update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off auto updates in Google Store did not stop the phone updating, even after a reset.
I pressed on an updating app until download manager appeared, then I disabled it. Seems to have stopped.

Comment: This sounds like a helpful suggestion, but I don't quite follow. Do you mean you long-pressed the notification to get the app info, and then disabled the download manager from there? If you can [edit] your question and explain a little further, it'll be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Found it on Nexus Grand Prime:
Settings - About Device (bottom) - Software Update (top) - Set 'check for updates' (Auto-Update) to Off.

The update wanted 530mb free space! Like hell, that space is reserved for game recording :).

Answer (score 0):

On my LYF Flame 2 device in India, I tried Krystalblue's answer and could only limit the software update to  "weekly", "wireless only" and disabled "Allow auto-update over WiFi...".
Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Found option to disable automatic updates in developer menu on Android 7. (click many times on build number in about phone to enable that menu)

Comment: This seems specific to some vendors/models; there's no option to disable automatic updates inside the developer menu on Nexus devices line.

Comment: @AndrewT., possible. vendors can add/remove anything. I see it on samsung phones.

Answer (score 0):

On my OnePlus9 Pro I disabled the auto updates in the developer mode menu but apparently they are still forcing me to do an update. In fact so much that the phone says "If you choose not to do so now, this update will take place AUTOMATICALLY between 2 AM and 4 AM starting May 4th, 2021." WTF.