# Can I cancel an Android update?

Tags: updates, ota-update

My Motorola Ultra is running 4.4.4 and I've been holding off on upgrading to the next one since I don't want to lose any possibility of getting root. However, this morning when the notification popped up, I accidentally selected "Don't remind me, just update at this time", the time being noon tomorrow. When it tries to start the update, is there anyway I can stop it?

Answer (score 3):

I've already found this hopeful answer:

> I just spoke to Google directly. The Nexus 5 under settings, apps has
> something called Google Play services. Not store. If you uncheck the
> notification box in Google Play services and restart the phone the
> notification for the Android system updates will stop in the
> notification bar. Worked like a charm!
>
> From: [How do I skip an Android system update and stop its notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100991/how-do-i-skip-an-android-system-update-and-stop-its-notifications)

Moreover, if your devise had been rooted, you should be able to install [`Disable Services`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice) and find the `SystemUpdateService` under `Google Services` Framework. Disable it.

As you have device with Android Kitkat please read also that article: https://www.droidmen.com/how-to-stop-downloading-of-android-os-update-in-android-phone/

It should work.

Comment: I've edited my answer - new useful link added

Comment: My question is not about disabling notifications. It is about whether or not I can cancel a scheduled application of a firmware update.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding. You can cancel it for choosing `... later` option. But look... stopping service like in the link doesn't stay forever, you can enabled it again at any disired time

Comment: Again, you misread what I wrote. I hit :later", but I had accidentally checked "don't remind me, just do it".

Comment: wait for installation time, I'm sure there would be option to re-think ;-)

Comment: I hope you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no option to disable a in-progress update. Android upgrade is done by system ui. It will keep trying to download the incremental upgrade packages. After the download is finished, it will ask you to install the upgrade. And reboot upon your confirmation. You can decide not to install upgrade when it's prompting confirmation.